# Two variable induction problem

Tags: summation, induction, integers

I managed to prove $(1)$ of the following problem, but am completely stuck on $(2)$:

[image: (2)]

**My attempts:**

Let $S(k)$ be the statement
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k = \frac{n^{k + 1}}{k + 1} + E_{k}(n)$$

It is clear that $S(1)$ holds (LHS is sum of a simple arithmetic progression).

Now suppose $S(t)$ holds for some positive integer $t$.

I tried doing several things for the second induction step, two of which seemed to be promising:

1. Expressing $\sum_{r=1}^{t} r^k$ from $(1)$, which turned out to be a sum of sums and that was beyond my reach.
2. Multiplying both sides of the equation to obtain
   $$t\frac{k+1}{k+2} \sum_{r=1}^{t} r^k = \frac{t^{k + 2}}{k + 2} + E_{k+1}(t)$$
   From $(1)$ I deduced

$$\sum_{r=1}^{t} r^{k + 1} + \sum_{r=1}^{t}F_{k}(t) = \frac{t^{k + 2}}{k + 2} + G_{k+1}(t)$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{t} r^{k + 1} = \frac{t^{k + 2}}{k + 2} + H_{k+1}(t)$$
... and I would really like to say that $S(t)$ implies that (what appears to be $S(t+1)$), but I am not okay with most of the steps I "performed".

Does anyone have any hint or explanation that would help me battle with this second induction?

Comment: To deal with $\sum_{r = 1}^n r^k$, look at $$\sum_{r = 0}^{n} \bigl((r+1)^{k+1} - r^{k+1}\bigr).$$ Use a) telescoping, b) binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method requires using [complete, or strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction), but I think it's probably what the question has in mind.

We have
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1) \cdots (r+k-1) = \sum_{r=1}^n (r^k + P_1(r)), $$
where $P_1(r)= \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}a_{\ell}r^{\ell}$ is a polynomial with degree at most $k-1$. Now notice that the first part gives you
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1) \cdots (r+k-1) = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} + P_2(n), $$
where $P_2$ is a polynomial with degree at most $k$.

Now, by the induction hypothesis that $S(\ell)$ holds for $\ell < k $,
$$\sum_{r=1}^n P_1(r) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} a_{\ell} \left(\sum_{r=1}^n r^{\ell} \right)$$ 
is a finite sum of polynomials of degree at most $k$, and so is a polynomial $P_3(n)$ of degree at most $k$. Hence
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^k = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} + P_2(n)-P_3(n), $$
and $P_2(n)-P_3(n)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$, as required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a bit of a problem to see how the induction hypothesis (that $S(ℓ)$ holds for $ℓ<k$) implies the third equation. I mean, since we know that $P_1(r)=\sum^{k−1}_{ℓ=0}a_ℓ r^ℓ$ the sum $\sum^{n}_{r=1}P_1(r)$ can be found without additional information, or? (I assume that $S(k): \sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k = \frac{n^{k + 1}}{k + 1} + E_{k}(n)$). Truth is, I am having difficulties with recognizing the line of thought here.

Comment: Point is, the induction hypothesis $S(\ell)$ tells you that $\sum_{r=1}^n r^{\ell}$ is a polynomial of degree $\ell+1$ (it also tells you the form of the first term, but we don't need this for this part of the proof). Thus the finite linear combination of them in $\sum_{r=1}^n P_1(r) $ is a polynomial of degree $k$, which is what you need for the conclusion.